# Mac OSX Programming for long time Linux geek

Tags: macos

I've written software on Linux since 1995 but must get up to speed with app development on the Mac.  I have no experience on that platform.   Obviously I should get my hands on some appropriate hardware.  What are good books, tutorial websites, and other resources for experienced devs getting started on Mac?   Not just APIs and app internals, but also including how does one install an app, debug it, etc?

Comment: I give a bit of advise to a novice mac programmer in this thread. Maybe that can be of some help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709441/pc-to-macbook-pro-transition-getting-restarted/2709533#2709533 . Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out some of the pragprog books:

http://www.pragprog.com/titles/tibmac/beginning-mac-programming

http://www.pragprog.com/titles/dscpq/cocoa-programming

Comment: The cocoa book looks interesting.

Answer (score 3):

For starters, I recommend [Apple's own developer docs](http://developer.apple.com/). They're pretty indepth, and cover a lot of areas, from UI consistency to the nitty-gritty.

For mac development, [XCode](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/xcode.html) is the way to go. It handles most of your needs, from building, testing, debugging, UI construction, and building the installer.

Mac OSX core API's work with C,C++,Objective-C, Python and IIRC Ruby. If you're looking to transition from Mac development to iOS development, then Obj-C is probably your best bet.

Comment: Well, for C++, let's rather say they _work with C++_ than _they support C++_. There's no public C++ API (except the STL) on Mac OS, but you can call Objective-C methods and C functions from it.

Comment: Several questions & answers here on SO got me curious about Obj-C, so I'm looking forward to mastering it.  But I think the projects I'll be paid to work on will be C++.

Comment: Support for pyObjC (python interface) was recently dropped by apple. Ruby is still an option (through MacRuby), and of course all the C derivates.